# vuejs2 copy clipboard issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, clipboard.js

I am trying to use https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-clipboard-copy/ for copy clip board feature in Vue.js,  it is working fine for string but when I have an object, it is not copying properly. Below is the sample code.

```
<button v-clipboard:copy="test">Copy</button>
```

if  `test` is a simple string then I am getting that string properly copied to clipboard as `abc` in this case.

```
data() {
        return {
            test: 'abc'
        }
    }
```

But when I give,

```
data() {
        return {
            test: {name: 'abc'}
        }
    }
```

I am getting `[object object]` into my clipboard instead `{name: 'abc'}`

Comment: I want the entire object to be copied. If it has multiple properties, all those properties too.

Comment: Can you try *JSON.stringify*  test and then when you use *JSON.decode* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button v-clipboard:copy="JSON.stringify(test)">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
<button v-clipboard:copy="stringConvertion">Copy</button>

  computed:{
   stringConvertion: function () {
    return JSON.stringify(test);
   }
  }
```