# Copy data(text) to Clipboard in Vue(Nuxt js)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I click the `vs-button`, the `single_download_link.pdfId` should be copied on clipboard.
I tried like this. But it was not working. And I will not use `v-clipboard` node module.
Please help me. Regards.

**DOM code**:

```
<div ref="text" class="w-full">{{single_download_link.pdfId}}
</div>
<vs-button block @click="copy()">
    Copy this link to clipboard.
</vs-button>
//this is my function

<script>
    import "../../assets/css/products.css";


    export default {
        name: 'Products',
        components:{
            Vinput,
        },
        data () {
            return {
                single_download_link:{
                    pdfId:"",
                    pdfRandomName:"",
                    uploaderUserName:"",
                    uploaderUserId:"",
                    uploaderUserEmail:""
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
            copy(){
                this.$refs.text.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');
            },
        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Update 2021:

***document.execCommand() is marked as depreciated***

**Alternative**.

Simply

```
copyToClipBoard(textToCopy){
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);      
},
```

### Previous answer:

This worked for me, just put it into your methods and pass any `String` you wanted to copy.

```
copyToClipBoard(textToCopy){
            const tmpTextField = document.createElement("textarea")
            tmpTextField.textContent = textToCopy
            tmpTextField.setAttribute("style","position:absolute; right:200%;")
            document.body.appendChild(tmpTextField)
            tmpTextField.select()
            tmpTextField.setSelectionRange(0, 99999) /*For mobile devices*/
            document.execCommand("copy")
            tmpTextField.remove()
        },
```

Comment: if you get [Object Objcet] in paste simply add JSON.stringify(yourValue) to make it a string. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588622/vuejs2-copy-clipboard-issue